# Need help implementing Burn Logic in an ERC-20 token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, tokens, contract-design

I am learning solidity and have decided to program my own ERC-20 token. I have inherited the ERC-20 Open Zeppelin standard, but would like to add some functionality that calculates 5% of every transfer, and then burns that amount from the total supply. Here is what I have so far:

[image]

1. I have created two functions: calculateBurnAmount, and burn. These functions calculate 5% of the amount being transferred, and then call the OpenZeppelin burn function while passing it that amount.
2. In order for the smart contract to "know" to burn tokens on transfer, they have to be called in the transfer function itself, correct? Did I correctly implement this by listing the transfer function and then calling the two burn functions in the logic body?

Answer (score 0):

In `transfer` function first calculate `amountToBurn` then subtract it from `amount` to get `amountToTransfer`.

```
uint256 amountToBurn = calculateBurnAmount(amount);
uint256 amountToTransfer = amount - amountToBurn;
_transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amountToTransfer);
_burn(_msgSender(), amountToBurn);
```

remove `burn` function

Comment: Hello thank you: I made the changes you suggested. DO lines 29 and 30 make sense? Also do I need to edit the transferFrom function to burn from sender and NOT msg.sender?

Comment: All balance checks are controlled by OpenZeppline ERC20 in _transfer function, and transferFrom also use _transfer function

Comment: How do I enforce minimum supply?

Comment: after _burn check `assert(_totalSupply >= _minimumSupply);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess there's a mistake in your `calculateBurnAmount` function, at *line 29*:

```
require(_balances[msg.sender] >= _balances[msg.sender] + burnAmount);
```

Imagine a user has a balance of **40** tokens. He wants to transfer **20** of them, so the burn amount required for a successfull transfer will be 20 * 5% (20 / 20) = **1**.
Back to your code logic:

```
require( 40 >= 40 + 1)
```

As you probably see, your function will not be executed, because the required condition will never be met due to basic math axioms.
So, the correct requirement at *line 29* should be:

```
require(_balances[msg.sender] >= _amount + burnAmount);
```